# ¿Porque el Recycler View a veces carga el Json obtenido y a veces no?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-volley

Ante todo muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta. Soy nuevo en esto y espero formular la consulta correctamente.
Tengo una app la cual consulto a través de volley una URL que me regresa un Json. Luego este Json es llevado a cada uno de los items que, están en un Cardview, que este se encuentra en un RecyclerView.

El tema es que esto funciona a veces!, es decir una vez me carga el Recycler con los articulos y otra vez no... testeo con una TOAST la veces que no me carga el Recycler y veo que si me trae el JSON pero no lo refleja... intente con un asyntask y nada...

mi app tiene login por tal motivo para probar si carga el Recycler tengo que desloguearme y luego loguearme otra vez para ver si tengo suerte y me carga el recycleview.

Mi clase que genera el llenado del recycler

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<ArticulosBean> list = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArticulosAdapter pAdapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static final String URL = "https://www.servicioswebtsas.com/WebServicePedidos/lista_articulos.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    pAdapter = new ArticulosAdapter(list, getApplicationContext());

    // Create grids with 2 items in a row
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    Log.d("HOLAA", response.toString());
                    //ATENCION: ACÁ TENGO QUE PONER UN IF POR SI NO HAY ARTICULOS EN BASE DE DATOS. LA BASE NUNCA VA A ESTAR VACIA.
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        ArticulosBean articulos = new ArticulosBean(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_articulo"),
                                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen_url"), //PUEDO PONER UN STRING GRACIAS A LA LIBRERIA PICASSO EN ADAPTER
                                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("precio"),
                                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("stock"));
                        list.add(articulos);
                    }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("PENDRIVE", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("ERROR LISTA", error.toString());
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}


//METODO QUE ESCUCHA BOTTON REGRESAR Y PREGUNTA SI REALMENTE QUIERE SALIR.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Add the buttons
    builder.setMessage(R.string.msg_salir);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.msg_tit_salir);

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog

        }
    });
    // Set other dialog properties
    // Create the AlertDialog
    builder.show();
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

}
```

Comment: Cuando obtienes los datos los guardas en la lista que anteriormente le has pasado a tu adapter... pero ¿cómo sabe el adapter o la vista que el modelo ha cambiado? Creo que tienes que pedir que refresque de algún modo

Comment: gracias @PabloLozano por la pronta respuesta. No logro por ahi entender que me sugeris, pero otro dato que me falto exponer es que con WIFI la mayoria de la veces responde perfecto (98%) y el tema es con DATOS MOVILES. por eso intente con ASYNCTASK pero tampoco logra cargar la lista. Alguna sugerencia de como controlar el llenado de la lista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo te falta es lo siguiente:

Cuando obtienes los datos de la llamada, los metes en la lista que (supongo) es el modelo a mostrar (se la pasaste al Adapter en el constructor). Lo que no haces es avisar a dicho adapter de que la lista ha variado, que puedes hacer añadiendo justo después del bucle donde metes los elementos.

```
pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Creo que cuando te funciona es por lo que se llama una *race condition*: Tienes la respuesta antes de generar la vista por primera vez, pero cuando usas los datos móviles hay un ligero retraso en la respuesta que hace que ya se haya generado la vista, que luego no se actualiza nunca.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo Lozano, era eso lo que faltaba!. Muy gentil de tu parte.